# Compile with c++17 mac

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++, clang++

I can't compile with -std=c++17, I got :

```
error: invalid value 'c++17' in '-std=c++17'
```

However I update Xcode and clang.

My Clang version is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`
```

And I load the newest header like optional, I have to do

```
 #include <experimental/optional>
```

instead of

```
 #include <optional>
```

Comment: Try -std=c++17 or -std=c++1z

Comment: @manni66 Sorry it's a typo, I corrected

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @n.m. How can I compile with -std=c++17

Comment: Apple ships a compiler that's too old to support this flag. You probably need to switch to a version of llvm/clang not provided by Apple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode brings its own complete toolchain, including headers and the actual compiler.

`Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)` (which ships with Xcode 9.2) does not support the usage of the flag `-std=c++17` since its too old. The optional header is only included under the folder `experimental/`. Which is why you need to `#include <experimental/optional>`

In order to compile your program with c++17 support using the compiler which comes with Xcode 9.2 you need to use the `-std=c++1z` flag.

Xcode 9.3 will be shipped with `Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.30)` which has support for the `-std=c++17` flag. However the `optional` header is as of today still under the `experimental/` subdirectory. This might change during the betas.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I get with this tests:

```
#include <experimental/optional>


int main(int, char* []) {
    return 0;
}

g++ -std=c++17 -o test test.cpp
error: invalid value 'c++17' in '-std=c++17'
g++ -std=c++1z -o test test.cpp
```

Did you try the c++1z argument?
Also of note my test compiles without the -std=c++1z argument provided.

I think I'm on a newer version of OSX than you:

```
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
```

Comment: Yes but i can't write include experimental/optional I need to include just optional, but with c++1z i can compile, I will update then

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-std=c++1z` as flag.

Answer (score 0):

libc++ with c++17 support since macos 15

Answer (score 0):

`-std=c++1z` also works on Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)